# Using values in list to replace a substring in a separate variable

Tags: python, list, loops

I am new to python and I am trying to create a function that will replace a substring in one variable with values in a list in another variable.

```
listofstocks = ["NET","DAL","DG","KNDI"]
apiurl = 'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{}/advanced-stats'
```

I am not sure how to write the loop that does this but my expected output should be

```
https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/NET/advanced-stats
https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/DAL/advanced-stats
https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/DG/advanced-stats
https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/KNDI/advanced-stats
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for stock in listofstocks:
    apiurl.format(stock)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

The answer was:

```
listofstocks = ["NET","DAL","DG","KNDI"]
apiurl = 'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{}/advanced-stats'

for stock in listofstocks:
    hello = apiurl.format(stock)
    print(hello)
```

Answer (score 0):

do this(not with a variable):

```
listofstocks = ["NET","DAL","DG","KNDI"]
apiurl = 'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{}/advanced-stats'
for stock in listofstocks:
    print(apiurl.format(stock))
```

(with a variable)

```
listofstocks = ["NET","DAL","DG","KNDI"]
apiurl = 'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{}/advanced-stats'
for stock in listofstocks:
    fstr = apiurl.format(stock)
    print(fstr)
```